# agGrid Angular - add element (icon) on a row, column

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I'd like to know how can I add an icon to a row, something like in the picture below. I did my research on google, but found nothing helpful.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVIVw.jpg "example"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should create a new field in your grid with Column def something like this -

```
{
    headerName: "",
    field: "icon",
    width: 100,
    cellRenderer: function(params) {
        return '<span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span>';
    }
}
```

This will display an icon on the rightmost field.
However if you want your icon to respond to events or perform actions then you should look into implementing a cell Renderer component as described [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/#angular-cell-render-components).

Comment: This is simply showing me an empty cell when I use this. I've also tried using <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>, but it only displays the literal text `edit`. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your css then:

```
cellStyle: { 'justify-content': "flex-end" }
```

or

```
cellStyle: {textAlign: "right"}
```

Comment: That's just for moving the icon to the right end. My question is, how can I add the icon to the row?

Comment: edit your question with some html and how you tried to do it. We will figure it out after.

Comment: you probably just need the oldschool *ngIf to control show/hide