# Ag Grid Cell Renderer Icons are not Clickable React

Tags: reactjs, onclick, icons, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I have a simple cell renderer that returns an icon:

```
import React from 'react'
function ActionRenderer(params) {
  const editRedirect = (e) =>{
    console.log("Clicked");
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <span class="actionIcons editIcon">
        <i onClick={editRedirect} class="fas fa-edit" href="/details"></i>
      </span>
    </div>
  )
}
export default ActionRenderer
```

When I create my AgGrid component, I also defined a `onRowClicked` event.

```
 <AgGridReact
        columnDefs={columnDefs}
        defaultColDef={{ width: 160 }}
        rowData={rowData}
        frameworkComponents={frameworkComponents}
        onRowClicked={rowClicked}
      ></AgGridReact>
```

As a result, my icons are not clickable, but the row below them is. How do I make it so that the icons are clickable, but if a row is clicked outside of the icons, then the `rowClicked` function runs? In other words, the row click is overriding my icon click, and I was to change that.

```
const frameworkComponents = {
    //  buttonRenderer: ButtonRenderer,
    progressBarRenderer: ProgressBarRenderer,
    actionRenderer: ActionRenderer,
  }

  const columnDefs = [
    {
      headerName: 'Full Name',
      field: 'name',
      unSortIcon: true,
      sortable: true,
      filter: true,
      lockPosition: true,
    },
    {
      headerName: 'Actions',
      field: 'actions',
      width: 140,
      lockPosition: true,
      cellRenderer: 'actionRenderer',
    },
  ]
```

Comment: can you post your columnDef? seems like you are not extending Component. check example here - https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/#example-rendering-using-react-components

Comment: @PratikBhat Done! Thank you for taking a look. I think that you do not need to extend Component when you define it that way I did (not as a class but as a function). I may be wrong though.

Comment: check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53327329/aggrid-angular-add-element-icon-on-a-row-column/53330662#53330662. Although it is for angular, the essence is the same. If you want icon to be clickable it needs to be a special component

Comment: @PratikBhat You say in your answer to use a cellRenderer. This is essentially what I am doing. The cell renderer returns a simple icon. I do not quite see how my current code differs from what you suggest.

Comment: You missed the fine details - However if you want your icon to respond to events or perform actions then you should look into implementing a cell Renderer component https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/#example-rendering-using-react-components

Comment: @PratikBhat My problem is not with how I use the cell renderer (which I am already using as seen from my columnDefs). If I replace the icon with a `<button></button>`, everything works fine. I am not sure how to proceed. Thank you for trying to help!

Comment: have you tried onClick on the span element instead?

Comment: @PratikBhat I have, and it doesn't work. Only works on a button. Unsure why the row below the icon's event gets triggered rather than the top element.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me :

```
 columnDefs=[
    {
          headerName: 'Actions',
          field: 'ACTION',
          sortable: true,
          filter: true,
          resizable: true,
          cellRenderer: function (params) {
            return '<span title="Edit" ><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt edit" data-action-type="edit"></i> <span title="Delete" ><i class="fas fa-trash delete" data-action-type="delete"></i></span>';
          },
    ]


    <ag-grid-angular
                  [pagination]="true"
                  [paginationPageSize]="15"
                  [rowData]="rowDataBlackList"
                  [columnDefs]="columnBlackList"
                  class="ag-theme-material"
                  style="height: 500px"
                  (cellClicked)="onCellClicked($event)"
                  #agGrid
                >
     </ag-grid-angular>
```

On click of cell do the following :

```
    onCellClicked($event) {
     if($event.column.getColId()=='ACTION')
      {
        let actionType = $event.event.target.getAttribute("data-action-type");
        switch(actionType) {
          case "edit":  
             {  
               console.log("Edit action clicked");  
               break;
             }  
          case "delete":  
             {  
               console.log("Delete action clicked"); 
               break; 
             }  
         }
   
      }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using button tag instead for span and icon inside button you can remove background using css.